# Testing EJB 3.1 applications with Embedded containers

Tags: unit-testing, ejb, ejb-3.0, ejb-3.1

Is it possible to call testing a bean or bean method (or a unit) after deploying it on an embedded container as  "Unit Testing".  IMO, I feel it is possible because,

1. We are still going to test only a single unit, may be a single EJB or its method, which does not depend on any other application code from any other developer.  But, ofcourse it takes the services from the embedded containers.
2. IMHO, we can consider these embedded containers are just a few jars that provide some service just as JRE provides a normal java SE application.  So, if we consider testing a java SE class or a method in JRE as Unit testing, then I guess we can call the above scenario as Unit testing too.

I agree that there is quite a lot that can be debated on this topic and I also do agree that what I mentioned above may not be right.  So I would like to hear from you all if what I am thinking is right or if I am missing some point.  As far I see, there is no single and solid definition for Unit testing.  If there are any, kindly provide me some pointers and it will be of great help to me.

Thanks a lot for your support.
- Ganesa...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the answer entirely depends on what are you doing in your tests.

According to the definition of unit testing,  [(it) is a method by which individual units of source code are tested to determine if they are fit for use.  A unit is the smallest testable part of an application](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unit_testing). If you need an embedded container to test that smallest unit of code, then yes, it is unit testing.

An example for me would be using a Hypersonic DB for DAO testing. It is not possible to test JPA queries without an in-memory DB (as far as I know) and they are the smallest part of the code of a DAO method.

However, if you are using an embedded container to test an EJB method and they way it collaborates with other injected EJBs or POJOs (e.g. via CDI) then I would consider this integration testing. You are now not testing the smallest bit of code but also something else (other collaborating EJBs or POJOs) and you would need to mock the collaborators to truly test the smallest chunk of code of the EJB.

Comment: In my case, my EJB would not be collaborating with other EJBs, but only take the services that the container provides.  For example, my EJB would use the configured message queues, destinations, security related configurations etc. just to make sure that they would not break when deployed in the container.  Ofcourse, I plan to deal with it in 2 levels.  First, just mock everything and test only the unit.  At the second level, I want to go a little ahead and test if my unit works on an embedded container before I integrate it with other application code.

Comment: In this case, according to you, we may call it as Unit testing.  Am I right?

Comment: Your second level testing I would consider it integration tests. You already have your unit tests that make sure small chunks of code are correct. Your "second level" tests are more oriented to make sure that configuration is ok - I am reluctant to include any configuration tests as part of my suite of unit tests.

Comment: Ah okie.  Thanks for your inputs on this :-)